# Is there any point in writing javadocs for a javafx application?

Tags: java, javafx, javadoc

Simple question here. Is there any point in applying javadocs to methods in a javafx application.

For starters - the majority of my method headers are formatted as `private` (with `@FXML` annotation). 
I am using some `public` methods - but what is the point in `javadocs` if the end user uses a `GUI` to interact with the application and my application isn't an `API`? Obviously, all my methods are concisely commented - but I don't see what benefit `javadocs` will have for users or future developers of the code.

Am I wrong? If so, I'd really appreciate your views on this.
Many thanks.

Comment: If your project ever gets developed by a *team* instead of just you, you're gonna want those docs. =) --- Docs (javadocs or not) rarely exist for the main/current developers...Someone working actively on a project tends to have their own internal map of where each thing is and what each thing does...And for most people this only starts to fail for considerably larger projects. --- You do documentation for the people who are *not* working on the project right now; even if you don't expect anyone other than you or your current team to work on it; simply because this might change.

Comment: Ok thanks @TheLima. Even re. `private` `@FXML` methods?

Comment: Yep...In theory, every method you can fully document should be documented. --- However, in practice, you will probably balance Docs with how important and/or intuitive the methods are; although, talking about Javadocs and similar specifically, I still recommend you at least specify the expected parameters and output, even for those, as many IDEs support them and it's easier to look at what they are from a JavaDoc tooltip popup like NetBean's, than to have to open the class/method source-code to look at the inline comments.

Comment: I'll follow your advice - I didn't want to end up with poorly documented code and just wanted to confirm good practice on this. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/85910/is-it-wrong-not-to-create-javadoc-for-my-code

In theory, meaningful documentation is never bad, and therefore every method you can document in a meaningful way should be documented.

In practice, it comes down to who the "audience" for the documentation is, to team-agreement, and to personal choice.

Things to consider are:

1. Your audience can be a maintenance developer, which, nevermind other persons, ***may be yourself***, after 3 years without working or visiting the project, and after you have forgotten the details of how it all works.
2. In case of Javadoc and similar documentation tools and standards, even for private methods (usually not outputted to external doc files by default), many IDEs support Javadocs (or similar) and implement extra-features based on them. NetBeans, for example, can display tooltips containing the types, names, and if you documented them, purposes of classes, methods, and input and output parameters and vars. ***Eliminating the need to open files and/or look at source-code inline-comments*** if and when you forget something.

Answer (score 0):

For framework code, I always Javadoc all public and protected members. For application code, I generally don't bother with Javadoc comments, but I do use inline comments to explain what a method is doing.

For private methods (whether framework or app code), I don't use Javadoc at all, since they aren't included in the Javadoc output by default. I do use inline comments for private members, though.

Comment: As I explained in the comment to OP, even for private methods, JavaDocs can still be useful, as many IDEs support them, and can show you tooltips based on them, which eliminates the need to open the files and/or look at the source-code for the inline comments. --- In this case, documentation is always recommended, although, as with pretty much anything in programming, it all depends on personal choice and/or experience.

Comment: @TheLima How would you be using (in any sense) a private method if you didn't already have the source code open?

Comment: For example, if you have a large file, private class or method, the tooltips can give you access to the javadoc explanations of other classes or methods, or even vars, within the same file, without you having to scroll the file to check inline comments.

Comment: Javadoc comments form the API specification of classes and their members. If you include implementation details in the doc comments, you make the implementation details part of the API, significantly hampering your ability to change the implementation in the future. This means you need both doc comments and inline comments for exposed methods, and inline comments for non-exposed methods. If your class is so large that finding things inside the code is an issue, the solution is to refactor it, not pollute the API with implementation details for your convenience.

Comment: *"If you include implementation details in the doc comments, you make the implementation details part of the API, significantly hampering your ability to change the implementation in the future."* - Only if you mistake the *map for the place* (fallacy). I can see where your argument comes from, but it's human mistake, not API problems. The documentation exists to document the classes and their members (the *place*), so if they change, so does the documentation (the *map*). If you avoid changing code to avoid changing docs, *wrong's on you*, not your API or docs.

Comment: @James_D As for *"If your class is so large that finding things inside the code is an issue, the solution is to refactor it, not pollute the API with implementation details for your convenience."* - You're basing the argument on an assumption that there are no situations where a class will be both big enough to take you off of your working space if you need to look something else up, and either outright impossible to refactor into smaller parts, or in which such refactor would *do more harm than good*. This is not the case; eg. just look at some of Java's core libs' methods.